# How can I only generate kotlin src files from the protobuf gradle plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers, gradle-plugin

I am successfully generating kotlin src files, but my code still seems to reference the java files because both java + kotlin are generated. I want to only use kotlin from my apps perspective once the files are generated. This is what I have currently

```
protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src"

    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.21.6"

    }
    plugins {. }

    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main").forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                id("kotlin")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generates something like this. I want to only expose `kotlin` src. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because the Kotlin sources are designed to build on top of the Java sources.  Without the Java source code, the Kotlin proto API is not usable.

Comment: Is it possible to hide java from the exposed src set though? And just have it in buildDir? I just don't want my other modules to be able to see the java impls. (eg it is allowed to generate java, but it should not be exposed to other places in my codebase).

Comment: What do you mean, it should not be exposed to other places in your codebase?  The other places in your codebase will _have_ to access APIs defined in Java.

Comment: If you define a `message MyMessage` in your proto file, and compile it for Kotlin, then the `MyMessage` class will be defined in Java, and any code that wants to create, read, or do anything else with `MyMessage` will have to use the Java API.

Comment: Other places in my code seem to reference the java impls if I check what they are calling (eg via the IDE Declarations & Usages feature)

If I have a proto called MyMessage

There is MyMessage.java and MyMessageKt.kt, and my code seems to reference MyMessgae.java. I do not want it to see MyMessage.java at all.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  What I'm saying is that there _is no_ "Kotlin impl" for those things.  `MyMessageKt.kt` doesn't define the same things as `MyMessage.java`, it defines different things that just add to `MyMessage.java`.  It's not like you can switch from the Java implementation to the Kotlin implementation; the things in Java are _only_ defined in Java.

Comment: What is the point of MyMessageKt then? What is the purpose of generating this if I cannot reference it from other places in my code? I understand that the Kt is adding on to the java impl, but why can I not only reference the kt version?

Comment: Imagine you had a file called `Foo.java` that defined `class Foo {}`.  Then you had a file called `FooKt.kt` that defined `fun makeFoo(): Foo`.  If you didn't have access to `Foo.java`, then you wouldn't even know what the return type of `makeFoo()` was, it would be missing.  That is basically how the Kotlin proto support is designed right now.

Comment: I see, but what is the point of the FooKt.kt then? It seems completely useless then?

Comment: It adds extra APIs to make using `Foo` easier and cleaner from Kotlin, and adds useful extension methods.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining Louis. I see the google documentation now too: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/kotlin-generated